# sorted key= does not apply to sublists

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I'm writing a unit tests, one of them checks a method that returns a list containing sub lists `[[],[],[]]`, the order of the sublists does not matter only the quantity of sublists and their values, the problem is that `TestCase.assertItemsEqual()` is deprecated and there is no `TestCase.assertElementsEqual()` method. To solve the problem I decided to sort the list returned from the method and the list from my unit test and compare the sorted versions, but the problem is that the sublists always have a None value and sorting raises a error:

```
>>> sorted( [ [None], [1,2] ] )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()
```

Actually my sublists always have 8 values where one is a None, and I have from 2 to 4 sublists.

So, I wrote a little lambda that changes a None to 0, because the ordering does not matter at all, I just need to assure that the order is the same:

```
>>> (lambda x: x if x is not None else 0)(None)
0
>>> (lambda x: x if x is not None else 0)(1)
1
```

But it does not work,

```
>>> sorted( [ [None], [1,2] ], key = lambda x: x if x is not None else 0 )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < NoneType()
```

The error message mislead me to think that changing NoneType to IntType would fix, but I know that the x value in the lambda is one of the sublists and that's why the lambda just does not work. But I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 heterogeneous comparisons no longer "just work". I think that the rationale for this change was that they return potentially unexpected results. Also: we can no longer specify a `cmp` function for customized sorting. So I think that you were on the right track trying to replace the `None` values.

You can replace `None` values with `0` like this:

```
L = [[None], [1, 2]]
normalized = list(list(0 if i is None else i for i in x) for x in L)
# list-comprehension alternative:
# L2 = [[0 if i is None else i for i in x] for x in L]
```

Then you can use `assertEquals` to compare the sorted lists:

```
expected_result = [[0], [1, 2]]
self.assertEquals(sorted(normalized), sorted(expected_result))
```

---

Edit:
Surely the following could be optimized, but if you needed a solution for arbitrary levels of nesting this is a start:

```
import collections
def replace_nested(L, replacement=0):
    if None in L:
        for i,item in enumerate(L):
            if item is None:
                L[i] = replacement
    else:
        for i,S in enumerate(L):
            if isinstance(S, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(S, str):
                replace_nested(S)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it right just after I asked the question, the problem was that the value passed to the key function was one of the sublists, so I only needed to walk the sublist and change None to 0 like you did with normalized, here is what I got:

```
# this sort a list with a sublist that has a None value in it - the None is changed to a 0 -
sort_none = lambda z: sorted( z, key= lambda x: [ 0 if y is None else y for y in x ] )
board = Board( [ 1,2,3 ,4,None,5 ,6,7,8 ] )
self.assertEqual( sort_none(board.valid_moves()),
    sort_none([
        [ 1,None,3 ,4,2,5 ,6,7,8],
        [ 1,2,3 ,None,4,5 ,6,7,8],
        [ 1,2,3 ,4,5,None ,6,7,8],
        [ 1,2,3, 4,7,5 ,6,None,8]
    ])
)
```

Thank you for your time